# Ajax progress bar using example module

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, progress-bar

I am new to drupal, currently learning about example module and its sub module, I already created the form using custom modules, in that form I wish to add progress bar for submit button, i referred many sites but, i can't get any clear idea, what i did for submit button is,

```
function custom_form_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['think/form'] = array(
'title' => t('Entry Free'),
'page callback' => 'custom_form_form',
'page arguments' => array('ajax_example_progressbar_form'),
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'description' => t('My form'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
'file' => 'ajax_example_progressbar.inc',
);
return $items;
}
and for submit button,

custom_form_my_form($form , &$form_state) {
$form['first'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('First name'),
'#description' => "Please enter your first name.",
'#maxlength' => 6,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => 'Submit',
);
return $form;
}
```

So, now how can I add progress bar in this submit button, when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is a difference between a progress bar and a progress indicator. A progress bar typically shows the progress of a request in a percentage, so it really depends on what you are doing and requires some more complex coding. If you are just looking for a progress indicator to let the user know that an ajax request is taking place, it is actually built into the ajax framework that drupal uses.

In order for your form to submit via ajax you need to define the ajax property on the form item that should trigger it:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_example_simplest_callback',
  )
);
```

would be about the simplest example.

there is plenty of documentation for this on the [API site](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)